rpart() decision tree fails to generate splits (decision tree with only one node (the root node))
I'm trying to create a decision tree to predict whether a given loan applicant would default or repay their debt.
I'm using the following dataset

library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

loans <- read_csv('https://assets.datacamp.com/production/repositories/718/datasets/7805fceacfb205470c0e8800d4ffc37c6944b30c/loans.csv')

Since the response variable default is encoded as dbl, I convert it to chr first and then fct type variable to use it in my classification model.
loans <- loans %>% mutate(default = factor(as.character(default), levels = c(0, 1), labels = c('repaid', 'defaulted')))

Now, I start building the recursive partitioning (rpart()) object, loans_model: The response variable is default and the explanatory variables are loan_amount + credit_score + debt_to_income.
loans_model <- rpart(default ~ loan_amount + credit_score + debt_to_income, data = loans, method = 'class')

When I make predictions with this model, all the predicted values get the same value, repaid.
loans$pred_default <- predict(loans_model, newdata = loans, type = "class")

unique(loans$pred_default)


Output:
[1] repaid
Levels: repaid defaulted

Also when I try to visualize the decision tree, I get only one node (the root).
rpart.plot(loan_model)

Output:

Can you help me understand why the model I built does not make appropriate predictions?
Edit: typo and added as.character()

What would you consider an appropriate prediction?

@StephanKolassa, thanks for responding. Okay, fct recoding is noted. I'll review the links you shared. I thought something was wrong with my code or dataset.

@StephanKolassa I'm just surprised that the dataset I'm working with, which has almost 40,000 observations and 13 explanatory variables, doesn't have an apparent structure that works with the rpart() classification. On a side note, could this be because the outcome variable default is imbalanced, in that far majority of the loaners defaulted.

TL;DR: You probably get a trivial tree because there is too little structure in your data for the model to pick up on. You get constant predictions because you have a trivial tree. And "hard" classifications are not a good idea; better to work probabilistically.

First, that recoding as fct does not change anything about the underlying model or how rpart() treats your data in this case. All this does is to make sure rpart() does classification rather than regression (i.e., numerical prediction) in the absence of a specific method="class" parameter. (But it is certainly better practice to replace 0 and 1 with the actual human-readable values. 0/1 is far more error-prone, and can easily lead to all kinds of misunderstandings. The times when it might have been necessary to save storage by recoding to 0/1 are long gone.) So this is not the issue.
It seems to me like rpart() simply sees no structure in your data that it could use to create a better model than a "climatological" one, i.e., one that uses the overall mean as a probabilistic prediction (check predict(..., type="prob")). Therefore the tree is trivial, with no splits.
You can test this, and whether there is an actual issue in your code (I don't see one), by only taking a subset of loans, e.g., one where default==repaid == loan_amount==LOW. This has a lot of structure that rpart() should absolutely pick up on and generate a single split. You could also take a slightly more complex subset that "should" lead to two or more splits. And so on. This would actually be a nice exercise in working with classification trees.
Once you have satisfied yourself that there is actually nothing wrong with your code, you can cut your data in various ways and check whether you find some structure that your model should be picking up on. I agree that features like yours "should" be predictive of loan defaults, but often enough, reality refuses to work the way we think it should, see How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?. Take a look at the other features in your data set. (You note that you have 13 explanatory variables. Yes, you do, but your model only uses three in your call to rpart().) Perhaps try a Random Forest.
Next, when you ask your model for class predictions, it uses its default threshold and classifies everything as repaid in predict(..., type="class"). The common default threshold of 0.5 optimizes for accuracy, which is usually not a good idea: Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?. Of course, since you only have a single leaf, you get constant predictions (both on the probabilistic and the "hard" level) for all instances.
The default threshold usually makes no sense and should be set based on the cost of actions and outcomes: Reduce Classification Probability Threshold. (Even better, stay on the level of probabilistic predictions, evaluate these using proper scoring rules, and separate the decision aspect from the statistical modeling and prediction aspect.)
You wonder whether the "imbalance" in your data might be problematic. It isn't. More precisely, it is only problematic to the extent that it ensures constant predictions... but even this would also happen if there was only a slight preponderance of repaids. The problematic part IMO is using "hard" classifications: Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?
